# Look for Javascript usage

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio

I've inherited a c# .net 3.5 project which I am task with converting to .net core.  This is pretty much done.

However, in this project there are A LOT!!! of third party javascript libraries and I am certain there are many of them that are not being used or not needed.

Is there a way to scan the whole project to see if any of the libraries are not used?

I know this is unlikely but thought I'd ask.

Thank you

Comment: One possible solution is : you can remove JS libraries from Master Page one by one and check the screen has any script issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome (but still valid with other browsers with little changes)
press F12 and click on "sources tab"

Then you can display all Resources used from your web page, images, css, scripts...

Or you can use a third party tool like this
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobertHoffmann.FindUnusedFiles

but personally i prefrerr to do it manually not using an automatic tool.

Comment: Great ideas... thank you :)